# running Robomongo on Centos

Tags: linux, mongodb

Is anyone succesfully running robomongo on centos machine.

I got this result when try to excuting it

```
> ./robomongo.sh 
./bin/robomongo: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./bin/robomongo)
./bin/robomongo: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./bin/robomongo)
./bin/robomongo: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./lib/libqscintilla2.so.8)
./bin/robomongo: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./lib/libQtGui.so.4)
./bin/robomongo: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./lib/libQtGui.so.4)
./bin/robomongo: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./lib/libQtCore.so.4)
./bin/robomongo: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./lib/libQtCore.so.4)
>
```

I have been try to update glibc from yum command

```
> yum list installed | grep glibc
glibc.x86_64                          2.12-1.107.el6_4.2               @updates 
glibc-common.x86_64                   2.12-1.107.el6_4.2               @updates 
glibc-devel.x86_64                    2.12-1.107.el6_4.2               @updates 
glibc-headers.x86_64                  2.12-1.107.el6_4.2               @updates 
> sudo yum update glibc.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.biz.net.id
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: centos.biz.net.id
 * rpmforge: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * updates: centos.biz.net.id
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
>
```

please, is anyone could solve this problem?

-Mardi

Answer (score 3):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/252), Robomongo supports CentOS starting from 0.8.1. Download the latest version - and it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like *robomongo* is build against a different glibc than you have, and hence it's not working. I would suggest you just compile it yourself from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

windows and MAC binaries are available if you want to add scons, cmake, QT5 and build robomongo on your centos box

Answer (score 0):

i think you should run:

```
sudo yum install -y glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686 libgcc.i686
```

goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link and download the latest version of robomongo.
http://app.robomongo.org/download.html
Example: 64 bit .tar.gz

Then extract the zip file. and goto extracted_folder_path/bin/
Then start robomongo.sh using command

> ./robomongo.sh